# Replace cursor with image when hovering over background 1

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, cursor

I am trying to show a png instead of my cursor for stage 1 of my website.
The background image transitions are in jQuery and the rest in PHP, CSS, HTML.
I researched and used a code that everyone seems to use but the cursor won't show up. I checked if the naming of the image is correct and the path.
Inspect element on Chrome shows no errors either.
Let me know if you can find the mistake...

The cursor should appear with the first background only ("top").
Any tips highly appreciated!

**CSS:**

```
.top {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
     z-index: 100;
     width: 100%;
}

.top: hover {
    cursor: url("images/cursorcamera.png");
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', 'audio/camera.wav');

    $('*').click(function(){
        audioElement.play();
        $('.top').fadeOut('slow')

       // $('.second').fadeOut('slow').delay(1000);
        $('.second').delay(5000).fadeOut();
        $('#counter').delay(5000).fadeOut();
   });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure you don't want a space between `:` and `hover`.

Comment: Not to mention, the cursor would only be on the element if it's `:hover` anyway, so just simplify and put the `cursor` rule on the `.top` without bothering with `:hover`.

Comment: Thank you - I tried that too but does not make a difference. Have also replaced it with a new image to check. No errors on loading the image either.. Can anything else block the cursor from appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use hover. Declare the curser url in your top css Element and it will work when you hover over the Element with your mouse.

Comment: I am not using hover anyomore. Have changed the code to the above and the pointer works. So must be the url somehow. I have tried with "" or '' or without. Still does not show up.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and the pointer shows up, not the image...so it works somehow just not the image...
          .top {
           position: absolute;
           top: 0px;
           bottom: 0px;
           left: 0px;
           right: 0px;
           z-index: 100;
           width: 100%;
           cursor: url(images/cursorcamera.png), pointer;
           }